# Cannot access video load progress in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video, preload, video-player

I'm trying to make a video player with several features by js html and css, but when I came to trying to preload the video, I couldn't find a way to know how much of the video was downloaded, and I need to know this info so I can update a progress bar to tell how much data has been buffered.

Is there a way to find out how much a video has been buffered?

I tried accessing the video <kbd>preload</kbd> property in javascript to get how much it was preloaded . but it gave me the preload type of the video

Comment: This should be some use to you hopefully: [show download progress](https://adnan-tech.com/show-progress-of-download-with-remaining-time-javascript/) Basically it shows how to setup an `XMLHTTPRequest` and then gives you the JavaScript so that you can show the download progress. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use: [TimeRanges](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TimeRanges) to know the length of loaded (buffered) video. 
There will be more time ranges added if you seek into a new area that has not yet buffered. Either handle such situation or else code your UI to *not respond* if a user clicks outside the fill area (*eg:* only clicking within fill area will change `currentTime` of video).

Also read: [Media buffering, seeking, and time ranges](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/buffering_seeking_time_ranges) guide for more knowledge.

Below is some testable code as a starting point to expand:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video id="myVid" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="your_file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<br><br>

<div id="myProgress_BG" style="width: 320px; height: 30px; background-color: #808080">
  <div id="myProgress_Bar" style=" width: 1%; height: 30px; background-color: #00A0E6" ></div>
</div>

</body>

<script>

let timeLoaded = 0; let timeTotal = 0;

//# access the "fill" (blue) bar
let prog_Bar = document.getElementById('myProgress_Bar');

//# get the max width for the "fill" (is same as BG width)
let prog_Max = document.getElementById('myProgress_BG').style.width;
prog_Max = parseInt(prog_Max);

//# set a listener for the "progress" event
let vid = document.getElementById('myVid');
vid.addEventListener('progress', (event) => { myProgressFunc() });

function myProgressFunc()
{
    //# update times (duration and buffered)
    if( timeTotal == 0 ) { timeTotal = vid.duration; }
    timeLoaded = vid.buffered.end(0);
    
    //# update width via CSS Styles (numbers need a +"px" to work)
    prog_Bar.style.width = ( prog_Max / ( timeTotal / timeLoaded) ) +"px";
}

</script>

</html>
```